# how to use sql using sql in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

How to use SQL to convert the first table to second table in oracle?

For the first table, it has three columns called Time, TotalUsers and Department. For the Department column, it only has two types of values, one is * another is null. I need to make TotalUsers with * intoTotalUsersStar, and make TotalUsers with null into TotalUsersNull in the second table. Please see the second table.

First Table:

```
Date      TotalUsers        Department
199905      1234                 *
199912      2345                 *
200005      8923               (null)
200012      6783               (null)
```

Second table:

```
Date         TotalUsersNull       TotalUsersStar
199905                                1234
199912                                2345
200005         8923
200012         6783
```

Comment: Do you mean that you would be creating a new table and filling it with data or you just want query result to be this way?

Comment: I just want query result to be the second table

Comment: You can use `CASE WHEN ... END` constructs twice.

Comment: yes, creating a new table and filling it with data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's very simple -

```
CREATE TABLE second AS
SELECT date
     , CASE department
         WHEN NULL THEN totalUsers
         ELSE NULL
       END AS TotalUsersNull
     , CASE department
         WHEN '*' THEN  totalUsers
         ELSE NULL
       END AS TotalUsersStar
  FROM first;
```

For more information [click here](http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_create_table_select_ctas.htm) or [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_7002.htm).

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! FYI, comments like "Thanks" are regarded as spam here. He receive your thanks implicitly when you upvote or accept our answers. Cheers!

Answer (score 3):

This is just a query.

```
SELECT Date_, 
       CASE WHEN Department IS NULL THEN TotalUsers END TotalUsersNull,
       CASE WHEN Department = '*'   THEN TotalUsers END TotalUsersStar    
FROM First;
```

Please note that I'm using field name `Date_` since Oracle does not like much when data types used as names.

To create a new table you will need something like this (assuming that you have **all the rights**):

```
CREATE TABLE Second
    (Date_ int, TotalUsersNull int, TotalUsersStar int)
;

INSERT INTO Second (Date_, TotalUsersNull, TotalUsersStar)
SELECT Date_, 
       CASE WHEN Department IS NULL THEN TotalUsers END TotalUsersNull,
       CASE WHEN Department = '*'   THEN TotalUsers END TotalUsersStar    
FROM First;
```

For simplicity I defined `Date_` field as `int`.

See my [**SQLFiddle DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/c370b/1).

Answer (score 0):

Try like this,

```
WITH
     t AS
     ( SELECT TO_DATE('199905','YYYYMM') date_, 1234 total_users, '*' department FROM DUAL
     UNION
     SELECT TO_DATE('199912','YYYYMM'), 2345, '*' FROM dual
     UNION
     SELECT TO_DATE('200005','YYYYMM'), 8923, NULL FROM dual
     UNION
     SELECT TO_DATE('200012','YYYYMM'), 6783, NULL FROM dual
     )
SELECT
     DATE_,
     CASE
          WHEN department = '*'
          THEN NULL
          WHEN department IS NULL
          THEN total_users
     END TotalUsersNull,     
     CASE
          WHEN department = '*'
          THEN total_users
          WHEN department IS NOT NULL
          THEN NULL
     END TotalUsersStar
FROM
     t;
```